# For $a,b,c>0$ prove that $\frac{a}{a+\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}} + \frac{b}{b+\sqrt{(b+a)(b+c)}}+ \frac{c}{c+\sqrt{(c+b)(c+a)}} \leq 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, fractions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

For $a,b,c>0$ prove that 
$$\frac{a}{a+\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}} + \frac{b}{b+\sqrt{(b+a)(b+c)}} +\frac{c}{c+\sqrt{(c+b)(c+a)}} \leq 1$$

Taken from local contest. I have no clue on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site. On Math.SE we look for more than just a statement of a problem - please see "How to ask a good question" http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question . In particular, you can edit this post to add additional context, most importantly the *source* of the question and the *motivation* for it. Is there any application for this inequality? What field of mathematics inspired it? Finally, if this is a contest problem, which contest is it from - which "local contest" in particular?

Comment: Should there be a '$+$' between the second and the third fraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because by C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}}\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a+\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}=1$$

Comment: How exactly does $\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)} \geq \sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{ac}$ follow from Cauchy-Schwartz?

Comment: @wilkersmon $(a+b)(c+a) \ge (\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ca})^2$.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!

Comment: @wilkersmon It's C-S exactly: $\sqrt{(a+b)(a+c)}=\sqrt{(a+c)(b+a)}\geq\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ca}=\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{ac}$